# В методе Java некорректно работает деление по модулю,не могу понять в чём проблема

Tags: java, условия, mod

Задание:напишите метод groupify, который принимает два параметра. Первый параметр - это строка, которую вы хотите разбить на группы. Второй аргумент - количество букв в группе.Пример: вызов `groupify(“HITHER”, 2)` должен давать результат :
`"HI TH ER"`.Если последняя группа не равна предыдущей,нужно добавить в конец строки `"x"`.Пример:вызов `groupify(“HITHERE”, 2)` должен давать результат :`“HI TH ER Ex”`.
Я написал код,и с первой частью задания он справляется,проблема в добавлении `"x"`.Я добавил проверку:

```
if (list.size() % num !=0){
    list.add('x');
    }
```

Но почему то это условие выполняется всегда,ложно оно или нет,хотя по условию "х" должен добавляться только когда при делении есть остаток.В этом и проблема.Вот код целиком:

```
public static void groupify(String word,int num){
        char input[] = word.toCharArray();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int number = num;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (i == number) {
                list.add(' ');
                list.add(input[i]);
                number += num;
            } else {
                list.add(input[i]);
            }
        }

        if (list.size() % num !=0){
            list.add('x');
        }
       System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Всё,разобрался,вместо деления по модулю массива с уже добавленными пробелами и входным числом

```
if (list.size() % num !=0){
            list.add('x');
        }
```

Сделал деление по модулю входной строки и входного числа

```
if (word.length() % num !=0){
            list.add('x');
        }
```

Теперь всё работает как надо.

Comment: У меня ваш код вывел `[H, I,  , T, H,  , E, R]`. Никаких `x`.

Comment: попробуйте вывести `list.size()` и `num`

Comment: @Suvitruf , у меня при вызове groupify("ABAAFHAF",2); выводит    
[A, B,  , A, A,  , F, H,  , A, F, x] ,хотя должно без икса выводить

Comment: @zRrr ,в смысле вынести их в отдельные переменные?Пробовал,не помогло

Comment: в смысле выведите их на экран и посмотрите что у вас там. Например для вашего примера из комментария у вас `list.size()` будет 11, `num` будет 2, остаток от деления не равен нулю, условие выполняется верно.

Comment: @zRrr ,спасибо,понял,но как мне тогда правильно записать условие?

Answer (score 1):

`groupify("HITHERE", 2);`

```
static void groupify(String word, int num){
    if(num <= word.length()){
       int startPos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length() / num; i++){
            System.out.println(word.substring(startPos, startPos += num));
        }
        if(word.length() %num != 0){
            System.out.println(word.substring(word.length() - 1) + "x");
        } 
    }else{
        System.err.println("incorrect num variable");
    }
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
HI
TH
ER
Ex
```

Немного подкорректировав код, можете вместо печати добавлять в массив или коллекцию, а печатать на выходе.